# result = ibm_db.fetch_both(stmt) -> Value is too long. SQLSTATE=22001 SQLCODE=-433

Tags: python, db2

The code is written in python 2.7 and I am using ibm_db to retrieve data from IBM DB2 10.5.5

When I request a relative large result set, I get the following error message:

> Exception: Fetch Failure: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0433N  Value "

Here is the piece of code:

```
CONN = ibm_db.connect<connection_info>
stmt = ibm_db.exec_immediate(CONN, sql_sentence)
result = ibm_db.fetch_both(stmt)
array_results = []

while result:
    document = result.get('PUSH_CONTENT').encode('utf8', 'replace')
    array_results.append(document.replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\" ?>", ""))
    result = ibm_db.fetch_both(stmt)
```

The error happens at this line:

```
result = ibm_db.fetch_both(stmt)
```

In the tests I did, if request up to 500 records it works fine, but if I request 600 it breaks.
Each line has a relative large amount of text.

Is there any limitation on the amount of data and/or records that it can handle?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think this is related to a data in an specific row, I had tested this already and I can retrieve the specific row.
The column type is xml
Thanks

Comment: the sql is pretty simple
    


select push_content from <table_name> where status = 0 and HTML_CONTENT = '' fetch first 500 rows only

500 rows works, if I increase it to 600 or more, it breaks

Comment: SQLSTATE = 22001 - SQLCODE 433; Significant data truncated during CAST to character. Cause Text: The length of the resulting character string is not large enough to hold the character representation of the value.. Are you sure your variable are right sized?

Comment: @Nifriz The error happens at this line

_result = ibm_db.fetch_both(stmt)_

To test your theory I tested only fetching the data

_ibm_db.fetch_both(stmt)_

and the error is the same, so it doesn't look related to this OR it is something in the library itself

Thanks

Comment: Have you verified that the same SQL statement works *at the command line* (i.e. outside of python)? The error seems to be coming from the server side.

Comment: @EdreiMarceloRibeiro this error usually is generated by insert or update sql instructions, not by select like in your case. So please try your SQL statement in DB2 consolle as **mao** advises, and tell us the result.

Comment: @mao Nifriz you are right, this error is being generated on the server (shame on me for not testing it before posting) thank you so much for your help

Comment: For those interested in the final solution, or the solution for the sql query itself, here it is:

_select push_content, XMLSERIALIZE(XMLELEMENT(name "html_content", d.html_content) as clob(2G)) AS "html_content" from <table_name> d_